HTML "I'm feeling luck" google button not working on all searches
I'm having an issue with the google page I'm trying to code using HTML.
The "I'm feeling lucky" button works on some searches. sometimes it directs to the page chosen immediately. And other times it shows the redirect page which I'm aware is normal.
However, I tried clicking the button after writing "harvard" in the search bar and it leads me to the page where it shows multiple search results.
here is the code:
 <form  action="https://google.com/search">
            <input class="searchBar" type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit" name="btnK" value="Google Search" class="searchbtn">
            <input type="submit" name="btnI" value="I am Feeling Lucky" class="searchbtn">
        </form>

I'm wondering if it's normal that it doesn't work with everything?

I am having the exact same problem right now! Can't believe this question is asked on the same day.. And what's worse is that the feature works fine on www.google.com for all searches. But on my html page it works only for some searches and not for others

You might try adding some parameters to your form's action URL to see if it improves consistency. For example, you could force the "I'm Feeling Lucky" feature by using https://www.google.com/webhp?btnI=I&q=harvard. However, this isn't guaranteed to work for all queries due to Google's internal handling.
